# Way to not use goto loops in vba msgbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a way to avoid using GoTo loops in VBA as i understand they can lead to serious confusion and issues. I have a  user `InputBox`, where the user defines a variables, currently on the if statement there are 3 options, if = Y ElseIf = N and else GoTo Start.

However this works great for the case where the user mistypes the variable i.e Y# etc, but i currently run into issues when the user wants to close the input box i.e clicks cancel or the cross.

So i was wondering if there is a more elligent solution to this or am I stuck with this hicup?

My code is below, this is only a test set used to test this new feature i am adding to my main code.

```
Sub MsgBox_Test ()

Dim TestVariable As String

VariableEntrey: TestVariable = InputBox(" Y or N")
If TestVariable = "Y" Or TestVariable = "y" Then
    MsgBox ("Yeyy")
ElseIf TestVariable = "N" Or TestVariable = "n" Then
    MsgBox ("Awww")
Else: GoTo VariableEntrey
End If 

End Sub
```

Thanks for any help you are able to provide

Comment: You have created and Endless loop if the user enters cancel or tries to close it. What do you want to happen in these scenarios ?

Comment: I know, this is  my issue, idealy I would like 4 possible branches, the Y bracnch, the N branch, a branch when there is a data entry like "y#" or "n#" or a mistype where there are redirected to re type and the last one which will cancel the loop. Does that make sense?

Comment: Is there a different outcome if they select No or Cancel?

Comment: Idealy if they cancel the box, the code should end or break. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub MsgBox_Test()

    Dim TestVariable As String
    Dim done As Boolean

    Do
        TestVariable = InputBox(" Y or N")

        done = True            ' preload exit value

        If LCase(TestVariable) = "y" Then
            MsgBox ("Yeyy")

        ElseIf LCase(TestVariable) = "n" Then
            MsgBox ("Awww")

        ElseIf Len(TestVariable) > 0 Then

            done = False       ' abort exit

        End If

    Loop Until done

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick repsonse, again unfdorutently I cant find a way to close the loop if i click the close or  cancel button is there a way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you ever so much :) Can i just confirm i understand the code now please. What does the LCase means? Returns the values to lower case? and so if the length of the string is grater than 1 you exit the loop. Is that true? If this is the case how does the loop end when you click the clsoe button? Thanks

Comment: also what does the option Explicit do?

Comment: lcase converts string to lower case.   .... there is no code that checks if length is greater than one  .... choosing "y" or "n" exits the loop. execution stays within the loop only if the length is greater than zero   ...... `option Explicit`,  put in this command line `abc123 = 456` and run the program again, you will see the answer  .... always use `option Explicit`

Comment: Thank you @jsotola for you help really appreciate it matey

Answer (score 3):

You can try a `Do... Loop Until` construct that just repeats until you get an acceptable answer. For example:

```
Sub GetAnswer()

    Dim strAnswer As String

    Do
        strAnswer = InputBox("Y or N")
    Loop Until strAnswer Like "[YyNn]"

    MsgBox "Thanks for your answer of: " & strAnswer

End Sub
```

See the docs on the [`Like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) operator to prevent having to check individually for `y`, `Y`, `n` and `N`.

Comment: Loved the `Loop Until strAnswer Like "[YyNn]"` part, nice :)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Unfortunately the code  dosent quite work as I would like it to, however this may be me in my understanding of the code. Ideallly I would need 4 possible outcomes 1 - "Y o y = Yeyy 2- N or n = Aww, 3 a string of 1 or more in length directs them back to the input box and 4 when the click cancel or the X to break the code. Does that make sense? Your way of putting the answers is fine dosent have to equal yeyy etc

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `Do .... Loop` here:

***Edit: plus limitation for single character or empty input***

```
Dim TestVariable As String
TestVariable = InputBox(" Y or N")

Do While (TestVariable = "N" Or TestVariable = "n" or Len(TestVariable) > 1)
    MsgBox ("Awww")
    TestVariable = InputBox(" Y or N")

Loop 

If TestVariable = "Y" Or TestVariable = "y" Then
    MsgBox ("Yeyy")
End if
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this works great apart from when the user tpyes in, lets say by accident, y# in this case would it be possible to redirect them back to the entering  stage? Thanks

Comment: @CptGoodar, try now with additional test for Text Length- now it should have only 1 character and if not it will be repeated by the loop.

Comment: Hi, unfortuently again, when you click the cancel button, it re loops back to the text entry still.

Comment: @CptGoodar, use `>1` instead of `<>1`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Do` >> `Loop Until` loop, to remove the `GoTo`.

Also, you can use `UCase(TestVariable)` to remove the `Or` from your `If`s.

```
Sub MsgBox_Test()

Dim TestVariable As String

Do
    TestVariable = InputBox(" Y or N")
    If UCase(TestVariable) = "Y" Then
        MsgBox ("Yeyy")
    ElseIf UCase(TestVariable) = "N" Then
        MsgBox ("Awww")
    End If
Loop Until UCase(TestVariable) Like "[YN]"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, unfortunetly when i type for example y# into the box the code ends, is there a way when this happens to restart the code and only end when the cancel or close buttons are used? Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the update, this code still runs into issues, when i click the cancel button the txt entry box re appears again. Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `MsgBox` instead of an `InputBox`.

```
Sub GetYesNo()
    Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult

    answer = MsgBox("Yes or No?", vbYesNo)

    If answer = vbYes Then
        'do something
    Else
        'do something else
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, this would work find but ultimetly the code that this snippet will work in will have many branches not just yes and no. But i really like your solution and will use it for parts where I only Yes/No branches. It simple, neat and clever. Thank you :)