# How to use match for extracting different values in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I need to extract multiple values from different rows that contains the same value with my given value (Range("A1").Value) and I want to extract them to (Range("B1").Value) one by one every time I press a button (using macro).

But my code extract wrong values.
Here is my code:

```
        Dim RowNum As Long, lastrow As Long, colnum As Long
        colnum = 14
        RowNum = 1
        lastrow = cells(ASht("M").Rows.Count, colnum).End(xlUp).Row
l01:
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(RowNum, colnum), Cells(lastrow, colnum)), Range("A1").Value) > 0 Then
            RowNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("A1").Value, Range(Cells(RowNum, colnum), Cells(lastrow, colnum)), 0)

            If Range("B1").Value = "" Then
                Range("B1").Value = cells(RowNum, 4).Value
            Else
                If Range("B1").Value <> cells(RowNum, 4).Value Then
                    Range("B1").Value = cells(RowNum, 4).Value
                Else
                    RowNum = RowNum + 1
                    GoTo l01
                End If
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found", vbInformation
        End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use `Find` instead of worksheetfunction match. Also look into using loops, rather running the macro "one by one".

See if this helps:

```vb
Sub findValue()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- change name here
    Dim rowNum As Long, lastRow As Long, colNum As Long
    colNum = 14
    rowNum = 1
    lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, colNum).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim rngFind As Range
    With ws
        Set rngFind = .Range(.Cells(rowNum, colNum), .Cells(lastRow, colNum)).Find(.Range("A1").Value)
        If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
            .Range("B1").Value = .Cells(rngFind.Row, 4)
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found", vbInformation
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

PS: I've removed the inner if conditions, because as far my understanding goes, you were doing the same thing regardless of the outcome.

i.e. `Range("B1").Value` will either be empty, or not equal to `cells(RowNum, 4).Value`, you are writing the value anyway. And if they are a match... well, the value is there already. Maybe I'm missing something in this logic.

Comment: Thanks dude, I just add a loop to end of your code and It works fine

Comment: `RowNum = RowNum + 1`

`GoTo l01`

Comment: That might be one way to achieve a loop, but is not the right way. See [Way to not use goto loops in vba msgbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47691661/way-to-not-use-goto-loops-in-vba-msgbox).